# Github Actions workflows per Terraform state file

Tags: terraform, github-actions

We have a single Github Repo that contains all of our Terraform code.
(We do not use Terraform Cloud)
The Terraform folder structure is broken up into various sections, for example:

```bash
├── global
│   ├── Route53
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── records.tf
│   │   ├── provider.tf
│   │   ├── state.tf
│   ├── IAM
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── users.tf
│   │   ├── provider.tf
│   │   ├── state.tf
```

The goal is to have a separate workflow per state file in order to keep the workflow runtime short and relevant to only those resources managed in the terraform state.

I am no Github Actions expert and want to know what is the best way to achieve this.
I have tried creating `.github/workflows/workflow.yml` files in each directory where a state file is located, but this did not work.

```bash
├── global
│   ├── Route53
│   │   ├── .github
│   │   │   └── workflows
│   │   │       └── terraform.yml
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── records.tf
│   │   ├── provider.tf
│   │   ├── state.tf
│   ├── IAM
│   │   ├── .github
│   │   │   └── workflows
│   │   │       └── terraform.yml
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── users.tf
│   │   ├── provider.tf
│   │   ├── state.tf
```

Thus far, the only way I could make it work to an extent, was to define the workflows in the root directory, and in the workflows file target the `working_directory` but this workflow runs on any commit to the our Terraform repo.   IE if we made changes to a completely different folder, for example `global/Route53` then the workflow will still run.  In such a case, I want a different workflow to run that is specific to the `Route53` resources.

```bash
├── .github
│   └── workflows
│       └── terraform.yml
├── global
│   ├── Route53
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── records.tf
│   │   ├── provider.tf
│   │   ├── state.tf
│   ├── IAM
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── users.tf
│   │   ├── provider.tf
│   │   ├── state.tf
```

```yaml
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: global/IAM
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
...
```

Comment: Are you looking for https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, Thanks for the information.  I review and post an answer asap